# Windows 7 can't boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

After a reboot (caused by a power loss) my PC with Windows 7 Ultimate can't boot up correctly, and give me this message:

"**can't find operating system**"

I have tried a lot to restore the Windows MBR with the Windows DVD but it appears broken and I can't boot it.

I have tried with linux rescue tools (like rescatux, boot repair and so on) with no result.

In the end I have tried to install a linux distro (Ubuntu 16.04) on a partition, in the hope that grub can magically repair the situation. In the grub menu i can see the windows SO, but when I select it I get the message:

"**not a valid root device**"

In my PC I have a UEFI bios, with two hard disk (one for SO and one for data).

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have an ISO image of Windows try creating a bootable windows disk, before that you said you are suspecting the Windows DVD is broken, have you tried changing BIOS setup to "Legacy" this helps boot external media (from experience), if you're sure its broken create another and choose "Automatically repair problems preventing PC fron starting" or rebuilt MBR

Answer (score 0):

Seems BCD problem.

You need a Windows 7 installation/repair media.

With your license key you can download Windows 7 from Microsoft, make a DVD/USB and then repair boot from HD.

For novice users it's best to use the automatic Windows 7 repair option.

See also [Repair Windows boot](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/repair-windows-boot.html) if you want to repair booting using command line.